# Is there a minimum rate that the AVPlayer can handle?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

Is there a floor on how low the AVPlayer can go on it's playback rate? I can't find anything in the docs about this. For example, can it play at a rate of 0.00001? 0.01?

Edit: You can set the rate to whatever you want, the question is, what's the slowest rate it can actually play at?

Comment: Try it. Does it work?

Comment: It get's set, but I can't discern the difference at a certain point.

Comment: Measure the total time to play a video and do a bit of math .. or go jump into the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum rate is dependent on the type of pitch correction that is enabled on the audio track. This is documented by apple here. https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationAudioSettings_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Time_Pitch_Algorithm_Settings

So you can either use `AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral` or `AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmVarispeed` to get your playback rate down to 1/32 speed. Alternatively you can also disable the audio tracks and get the same result.